# Responsive design for 'letterbox' Android tablets

Tags: css, responsive, short

I am designing a faux PowerPoint presentation that is to be web-based so that it can run on all devices. It runs in landscape format and it works fine on most devices but on screens that are proportionally short in height ,CinemaScope (as on my Android Tablet), I run into problems. Ideally, I would want to shrink the viewport height and reduce the side margins to bring in back to more 'normal' proportions. I could write an @media switch to narrow the outer div but I can't figure out how to test for proportion rather than width. Is there such a mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Use the media feature [`aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio):

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1601/900) {
  /* Styles for very wide screens */
  ...
}
```